# Logging in users while password encrypted

Tags: jakarta-ee, encryption, authentication, passwords, sha256

I'm developing an application with Java EE and actually having some trouble to find out how to validate users, the main problem is, Authentication being based on email and password while password is encrypted in the databse through Jasypt SHA-256 encryption algorithm.

Can I get an advice?

```
ConfigurablePasswordEncryptor passwordEncryptor = new ConfigurablePasswordEncryptor();
    passwordEncryptor.setAlgorithm( "SHA-256" );
    passwordEncryptor.setPlainDigest( false );
    String motDePasseChiffre = passwordEncryptor.encryptPassword( motDePasse );

    utilisateur.setMdp( motDePasseChiffre );
```

**EDIT**

So I have this `ConfigurablePasswordEncryptor passwordEncryptor = new ConfigurablePasswordEncryptor();
    valid=passwordEncryptor.checkPassword(mdp,utilisateur.getMdp());`

which returns a boolean, whether the plain password is the encrypted password or not.

I'm having Tomcat errors:

> org.jasypt.exceptions.EncryptionOperationNotPossibleException
>       org.jasypt.digest.StandardByteDigester.matches(StandardByteDigester.java:1106)
>       org.jasypt.digest.StandardStringDigester.matches(StandardStringDigester.java:1052)
>       org.jasypt.util.password.ConfigurablePasswordEncryptor.checkPassword(ConfigurablePasswordEncryptor.java:251)
>       projet.helpdesk.form.ConnexionForm.connecterUtilisateur(ConnexionForm.java:47)
>       projet.helpdesk.servlets.Authentification.doPost(Authentification.java:30)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
>       org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)

Comment: Please provide your code and a link to the Jasypt SHA-256 documentation you are using. Also note that hashing is not encryption. If you are using the Jasypt [`StrongPasswordEncryptor`](http://www.jasypt.org/api/jasypt/1.9.2/org/jasypt/util/password/StrongPasswordEncryptor.html) then that is a good method and the name is just unfortunate.

Comment: Putting user's security at risk, any risk, because a developer has not taken the time to understand correct security measures is not justifiable. See [How to securely hash passwords, The Theory](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords/31846#31846) on Security Stackexchange. See OWASP (Open Web Application Security Project) [Password Storage Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet#Leverage_an_adaptive_one-way_function).

Comment: Don't put "SOLVED" in the question, post an answer explaining how the problem was solved instead.

Comment: So i used these lines to hash the code using the SHA-256 Algorithm.
`ConfigurablePasswordEncryptor passwordEncryptor = new ConfigurablePasswordEncryptor();
        passwordEncryptor.setAlgorithm( "SHA-256" );
        passwordEncryptor.setPlainDigest( false );
        String motDePasseChiffre = passwordEncryptor.encryptPassword( motDePasse );`

Comment: The problem was solved after using the same algorithm hashing object
`ConfigurablePasswordEncryptor passwordEncryptor = new ConfigurablePasswordEncryptor();
     passwordEncryptor.setAlgorithm("SHA-256");
     passwordEncryptor.setPlainDigest(false);    setValid(passwordEncryptor.checkPassword(mdp,utilisateur.getMdp()));`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try encrypting the password from input , and check if the encrypted password(from Input) matches the encrypted password present in the database.

**EDIT**

Answers From the comments

Do not encrypt passwords, when the attacker gets the DB he will also get the encryption key. Just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security. Iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use a function such as password_hash, PBKDF2, Bcrypt or similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force

Comment: Do not encrypt passwords, when the attacker gets the DB he will also get the encryption key. Just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security. Iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use a function such as password_hash, PBKDF2, Bcrypt or similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force.

Comment: Encrypting the same password gives different results, there's no way to compare them that way.

Comment: @zaph Actually security doesn't count much in my application, it's gonna be used in a bank that is already secured from the outside

Comment: @TheNorth 1. Not encryption, hashing. 2. The same input will produce the same output. If you use a salt and iteration count it needs to be saved with the hashed password, that is common practice.

Comment: @TheNorth Oh, this is so funny I just emailed the comments to my Bank Auditor. Please let us know the name of the bank so we can be sure not to use it. Auditor: "Relying on a VPN, firewalls and TLS does not stop insider attacks or malware. If this is customer sensitive data it should be encrypted, even internally."

Comment: Actually you're not helping at all, probably there's a thousand way to encrypt secure data (password) doesn't mean that i have to learn them all, at least for now, because i have got only one month to complete this web app. And would be very pathetic if you thought for a second that what i'm gonna produce concerns the bank's clients information.

Comment: @TheNorth It might be wise to pass this task on to someone else in your team. Not trying to be rude, but if your approach to security is this relaxed, something **will** go wrong, and it will all collapse down to you!

Comment: @LukePark Okay i have presented this wrong, i'm making a prototype so no need to focus on this, and i'm very aware of the weight of this task.
And i wish i could get an answer on the real problem, i did read the jasypt documentation, yet i cant have it working, the same Tomcat error keeps happening.

Comment: @TheNorth Is it a requirement that you use SHA256?  Which, by the way, is not a password hashing algorithm and is not secure when used as one.

Comment: @LukePark Actually this is my very first web app, so i'm just passing by the basics.
I found out the problem, i used the SHA-256 algorithm to encrypt the password, and declared a different one when trying to check it.

You can tell me what methods i should use in order to have a secure web app, send me documentation, links.

Comment: @TheNorth Well first, you need to stop saying "encryption", this has nothing to do with encryption!  It is hashing!  You should be using PBKDF2, Bcrypt or potentially Argon2.  See if you can find an implementation for these and use them instead.

Comment: The problem with prototypes is that all to often the become shipping code with very little change. The problem with poor security is that it compiles and functions, just not securely and the poor security is probably not going to be noticed in a code review. Nor will the breach generally be noticed when it occurs, the attackers will silently take the data, potentially aggregating it, and sell it on the dark web.

Answer (score 0):

Do not encrypt passwords, when the attacker gets the DB he will also get the encryption key. Just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security. Iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use a function such as password_hash, PBKDF2, Bcrypt or similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force

Comment: The "Encryption" in the question isn't. SHA256 is a hash algorithm (on its own not a good choice for hashing password but on the right path).